# Truncate back of filename instead of front when not enough space in multi-tab vim

Tags: vim

If I don't have enough terminal columns to display all filenames in a multi-tab vim session, it truncates the front of the filenames in order to fit them all into the tabs:

With enough space:

[image]

Without enough space:

[image]

As you can see it has truncated the names from the front, which makes them harder to find. Can I reverse this behaviour to make vim truncate from the back of the name?

Comment: `:h setting-tabline` may be a help

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: There's no simple option for that, but the (GUI and terminal) tabline is fully customizable, so you can indeed tweak it according to your needs.**

[`:help setting-tabline`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#setting-tabline) both provides the documentation for tweaking the tabline as well as an example `MyTabLine()` function that

> is just a simplistic example that results in a tab pages line that
>   resembles the default, but without adding a + for a modified buffer or
>   truncating the names.

It then even mentions your wanted behavior:

> You will want to reduce the width of labels in a clever way when there is not enough room.

#### Implementing the truncation

In order to truncate from the right, you can use [`strpart()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strpart%28%29) (but it would be based on character count and requires explicit handling for non-ASCII characters) or [`matchstr()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstr%28%29). Combining the latter with the [`/\%v`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25v) regular expression atom, you can match for character width, handling tabs and double-width characters, too:

```
:echo matchstr('a 日本語 string that is too long', '^.*\ze\%>10v.*$')
a 日本語 s
```

Library functions like from my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) can deliver a truncation indicator in addition:

`:echo ingo#strdisplaywidth#TruncateTo('a 日本語 string that is too long', 10)`
`a 日本語 …`
`:echo ingo#avoidprompt#TruncateTo('a 日本語 string that is too long', 10)`
`a 日…long`

Comment: Very cool with the catering for foreign characters 'n all. Give me a day or two to actually fix this into my vimrc and I'll accept your answer. Unless you feel like spoonfeeding me the full vim syntax for settings-tabline :-]

Comment: Okay, have fun with it! This is all about personal customization; that's why I didn't provide (my own) full end result. If you develop this on your own (with some hints and tips from elsewhere), you'll be able to continuously adapt and improve it, and that's what Vim is all about!